# Virtualenv / pip installation log?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

Do `pip` or `virtualenv` keep a log of installations?

E.g. Say I create a virtualenv and install a package in it.

```
> source [my virtual env]/bin/activate
> pip install matplotlib
```

Is there a place where a log of the package installation is kept?

If not, what would be a good way to log package installations ? (other than manually copying the output of `pip install` to a text file)

Comment: What's wrong with `pip install matplotlib >> pip-install.log`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you run the pip, you can specify the logfile.

```
pip install matplotlib --log LOG_FILE
```

That file will contain the verbose log

for example,

```
pip install matplotlib --log log.txt
```

This will create a `log.txt` in the same directory and put the log in that.

Comment: That log is just what it writes to the stdout/stderr which is way less than the actual things that happen if the install is successful.

Comment: Please read the question again, it's about how to store log in file (`other than manually copying the output of pip install to a text file`); not what to log.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about keeping the logs, you probably care also about pip's [verbose option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#verbose)

> -v, --verbose
>   Give more output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.