# The program scss is not currently installed

Tags: python, css, installation, sass

I have been trying to install scss from [here](https://pythonhosted.org/scss/).  After sucessfully running `pip install scss`, I then tried to run scss as follows:

```
scss -i
```

However, I then got the error that

```
The program 'scss' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby-sass
```

This is confusing because pip says that scss was installed correctly, and that the commands it tells me to install scss with is not the actual way to install scss.  How can I install scss?

Edit:  This is a ubuntu platform and doing `import scss` from the command line resulted in the error `ImportError: No module named scss`.

Comment: This sounds like a PATH issue, what platform are you on?  Can you successfully `import scss` from the python interactive prompt?

Comment: Do you have to install the original `scss` as well from [here](http://sass-lang.com/install)?

Comment: @Justin, that was the problem.  Thank you very much.  If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: Are you sure?  It sounds like you just installed a ruby program (not a python one).  I just installed `scss` via pip in a virtualenv on ubuntu and it works fine.  I suspect that your `pip install scss` failed for some reason....

Comment: @rkersh My guess is that `python-scss` somehow uses the original `scss` program on your system, so if it isn't locatable, then it tells you to install it.

Comment: in my case to use Flask-Assets, `pip install flask-assets` , and to use the filter `pyscss` you must run `pip install pyscss`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the original SCSS/SASS installed from [here](http://sass-lang.com/install).

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, if I do the following, the python version of scss appears to work fine (mind you, I don't have experience with this module).

```
$ virtualenv so1
New python executable in so1/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
$ cd so1
$ source bin/activate
$ pip install scss
Downloading/unpacking scss
  Downloading scss-0.8.73-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking pyparsing (from scss)
  Downloading pyparsing-2.1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42kB): 42kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: scss, pyparsing
Successfully installed scss pyparsing
Cleaning up...
(so1)$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scss
>>> 
(so1)$ which scss
<path>/so1/bin/scss
(so1)so1$ scss -i
SCSS v. 0.8.73 interactive mode
================================
Ctrl+D or quit for exit
>>> 
Bye bye.
(so1)$
```

I've edited-out the paths above on my machine as those aren't relevant.

There should be no dependency on the ruby version of scss, as far as I can tell.  The only requirements are as stated in the python-scss documentation:

```
> python >= 2.5
> pyparsing >= 1.5.5
```

As I mentioned in the comments, your `pip install scss` probably failed for some reason.  You'll probably want to capture the [log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438550/virtualenv-pip-installation-log) as suggested here.